# React component running 8 times and the props are cleared except for 4th and 5th run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify, react-props, spotify-app

I am working on creating my first React web app with the spotify API. For the web app, you choose a specific date and it displays some of the popular songs released on that day. I then send an array of those songs though various components, all with no issues but one. I discovered that said component was actually getting the props correctly, then clearing them. Here is the code:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import "./TrackList.css";
import "../Track/Track";
import Track from "../Track/Track.js";
let i = 1;

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  getProps() {
    console.log(this.props.tracks);
    console.log("this component has ran " + i + "times.");
    i++;
  }
  render() {
    this.getProps();
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks.map((track) => (
          <Track
            track={track}
            key={track.id}
            onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
            onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
            isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

**The console will then output that it ran 5 times, and the correct array. It runs for a total of 8 times, and none of the arrays have anything in it other than the 5th one.**

**^^ array with song names in it is the correct one.

How come it is running multiple times and how do I stop if from clearing??

I have tried making new props and making it equal to this.props.track when i = 5, however my screen just went white.

The code looked like: **

```jsx
import React from "react";
import "./TrackList.css";
import "../Track/Track";
import Track from "../Track/Track.js";
let i = 1;

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fixedArray: [],
    };
  }

  getProps() {
    console.log(this.props.tracks);
    console.log("this component has ran " + i + "times.");
    i++;

    if (i === 5) {
      this.props.fixedArray = this.props.tracks;
    }
  }
  render() {
    this.getProps();
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.fixedArray.map((track) => (
          <Track
            track={track}
            key={track.id}
            onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
            onRemove={this.props.onRemove}
            isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Comment: A component's `render` method is executed when the component is... well... rendered. It is not a component itself that triggers 8 re-renders. It is its container that makes it re-render that many times. You need to walk from this component up to see what triggers re-renders.

Comment: Edit, for some reason when I make specific edits in the TrackList component and save it and go back, it works. I'm hoping that means it can be relatively easy to fix??

Comment: @RAllen when a component changes its state, it re-renders so yes, they can trigger their own render function

Comment: It sounds like caching changes your component's container behavior and hence the number of re-renders. Try to disable the cache in your browser's `Developer Tools ->  Network tab` and test again. The code you've posted doesn't seem to clear anything. Usually, it doesn't really matter how many times the component is re-rendered because it doesn't affect anything except performance in very rare cases when a component is extremely heavy, which is not your case. You need to go up the tree and see where re-renders are initiated. The component above doesn't seem to have anything with it.

Comment: @Phil you are right, but the component above (the first code snippet) doesn't change its state.